# Is there a way to use Ajax to monitor a file, and still update the file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am fairly new to web programming, and I am working on a project where a button is pressed on a webpage which uses Javascript to write a simple value to a text file through a basic php server file. The webpage also needs to have other bells/whistles, and I can make all of the required things work fine, but I would like to monitor the value in the text file so I can show the status on the webpage. I can get it to read the status using AJAX code, or I can get it to send the value to the server file, but I can't get both to work in the same program.

I figured that I would have to pause the AJAX code monitoring the file while I was writing from the Javascript, but no matter how I do it, I can't get it to work. I have tried toggling a variable and putting the Ajax code in an IF statement. I have also tried executing the Ajax in a While loop using the same variable.

An example of the code I have been trying is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var toggleBit;
if (toggleBit = 'on')
{   
    function saveXMLDoc()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","server.php?q=1!",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        toggleBit = 'off';
    }
}

if (toggleBit = 'off')
{   
    setInterval(function()
    {   
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4)
            {
                if (ajax.responseText == "1") {
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Faulted";
                    document.getElementById("p1").style.fontSize = "xx-large";
                    document.getElementById("p1").style.color = "Red";
                }else if (ajax.responseText == "0"){
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Okay";
                    document.getElementById("p1").style.fontSize = "x-large";
                    document.getElementById("p1").style.color = "green";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Unknown";
                    document.getElementById("p1").style.fontSize = "x-large";
                    document.getElementById("p1").style.color = "yellow";
                }
            }
        };   

        ajax.open("POST", "example.txt", true); 
        ajax.send();

    }, 500);
}
</script>
```

Then this is one of the many ways I have tried to set the variable stopping the AJAX code, and run the function to send the value to the PHP server file that writes to the text document. I tried separating it, and setting the disabling bit using an onmouseover event, which worked better, but when I run it, the status works, and I get an error saying it couldn't open the file when I pressed the button.

```
<p><b>System Status: </b><b id ="p1" > </b> </p>

<button type="button" style="color: white" onclick ="toggleBit = 'on';saveXMLDoc()">Emergency</BR>Stop</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

PHP Server file code:

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$myFile = "example.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 
$stringData = "$q\n"; 
fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
fclose($fh); 
?>
```

I'm not necessarily looking for someone to write the code for me, but if someone has a cleaner way to do it, or can just point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
}

setInterval(function()
    {
        // Include a timestamp to prevent caching:
        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'example.txt?t=' + new Date().getTime(), true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
, 500);

function write_number(value)
{
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'server.php?q=' + value, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>

<p>The value is: <span id="placeholder"></span></p>
<button onclick="write_number(1)">Emergency Stop</button>
```

You don't need separate AJAX objects for each function. Make it a global so it can be reused (see code).

There are a number of errors in your original code. It's hard to say what causes it not to work properly.

Also, you can't declare functions inside if-statements (or other scopes). This piece of code is invalid:

```
if (toggleBit = 'on')
{   
    function saveXMLDoc()
    {
    }
}
```

Put the if-statement *inside* the function instead.

Comment: Thank you very much @Midas. That is a lot cleaner than what I was trying. Also unlike mine, yours works. I figured I had errors; I had tried moving the if statements all over the place to get things working. I do have a couple questions though. I used the POST method to avoid caching when reading the text file. Is there a specific reason or benefit using the GET method with the time stamp instead? The other question I have is, without disabling the interval function, isn't there a possibility of a read/write collision? Thank you again.

Comment: @WillFleitz Generally, GET is for "getting" data from a server and POST to "post" data to a server. But I think both should work either way. To answer your other quesiton: I only used one AJAX object and since it can only make one request at a time, I don't think there will be read/write collisions.

Comment: Also, in my `write_number` function, it's a better idea not to include the actual value in `'server.php?q=' + value` but use some sort of identifier and make the value itself hardcoded in the PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

In this situations if I understood correctly i prefer to disable temporary the button on the Ajax send and immediately after the Ajax return i reenable the button. In this way i can check the status of the html element instead to use a local js variable